# MATLAB sound command

Tags: matlab, audio

I have to add part of the sound clip in MATLAB. 
The code I am using is :

```
 [y, Fs]  = audioread('song.mp3');
 samples  = [y,3*Fs];
 [y,Fs]   = audioread('song.mp3', samples);
 sound(y, Fs)
```

My question is that in `samples =[y,3*Fs]` what shall I write in place of `y` ? The sound plays but it plays after a considerable delay of 2-3 seconds. How to overcome that ?

Comment: The first `3*Fs` value of `y` is zero, right?

Comment: 3*Fs command is for playing the sound for 3 seconds.

Comment: Then, you want to record/listen the first 3 secs. So, why don' t you write samples = [1, 3*Fs]; ?

Answer (score 0):

I would have liked to comment on mehmets comment above, as that's pretty much the right answer - but I'll just elaborate a bit.

I would think your code above would produce an error, as you are trying to index the samples loaded from the file 'song.mp3' with the samples from the same song. If you want to access a part of a soundfile (i.e, the first 3 seconds), then you should (as mehmet correctly states) address it as such:

```
[y, Fs] = audioread([pwd '\sounds\pn.wav']);
[y, Fs] = audioread([pwd '\sounds\pn.wav'], [1, 3*Fs]);
sound(y, Fs)
```

However, a more elegant way, to avoid loading the file two times, could be to index/cut the sound file during playback instead:

```
[y, Fs] = audioread([pwd '\sounds\pn.wav']);
sound(y(1:3*Fs,:), Fs);
```